# Difference between two columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have two columns (`credit` and `debited_amount`) and I want to calculate the difference between them.

Only need to retrieve records greater than zero or if the `debited_amount` field is Null.

Never mind if the value is zero.

Here is the SQL query which I have tried. Please help

```
SELECT
  `p_Id`,
  `user_id`,
  `doc_id`,
  `credit`,
  `app_date`,
  `expires_on`,(credit - debited_amount) AS credit
FROM
  `wp_loyalty_credits`
WHERE
  `expires_on` > now();
```

Comment: So you can compare `expires_on` and `now()` but you cannot compare 2 other columns?

Comment: if the debited_amount is null the differnce of credit and debited_amount shows Null.In that situation I need the same credit value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to add the logic into the `where` clause:

```
SELECT `p_Id`,`user_id`,`doc_id`,`credit` ,`app_date`,`expires_on`,
       (credit -debited_amount) AS credit
FROM `wp_loyalty_credits`
WHERE `expires_on`>now() and (credit > debited_amount or debited_amount is null);
```

Your query redefines `credit` in the `select`.  However, that is irrelevant, because you can't refer to a column alias in the `where` clause.  So, the column `credit` is what it used.  It is clearer if you add table aliases:

```
SELECT lc.p_Id, lc.user_id, lc.doc_id, lc.credit, lc.app_date, lc.expires_on,
       (lc.credit - lc.debited_amount) AS credit
FROM `wp_loyalty_credits` lc
WHERE lc.expires_on > now() and
      (lc.credit > lc.debited_amount or lc.debited_amount is null);
```