# I need to get sum of difference of two columns in each row

Tags: php, laravel

i have a table called sales, there are 100 rows, table has 2 fields, namely total and commission, i want to get SUM(total-commission) of all rows into a single value

Comment: What have you tried and how is it not giving the results your after?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25077898/difference-between-two-columns-in-mysql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between two columns in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25077898/difference-between-two-columns-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can user Eloquent Builder `sum()` function.

```php
$sum = Sale::select(
           DB::raw('commissioned_total as total - commission')
       )
       ->sum('commissioned_total');
```

2. Or you can user Laravel Collection `sum()` function.

```php
$sum = Sale::all()->sum(function($sale) {
    return $sale->total - $sale->commission;
});
```

3. You can enhance this method more,

Define this `commissionedTotal()` function on `Sale` model, and use sum function as **Higher Order Message**.

**Sale Model**

```php
public function commissionedTotal()
{
    return $this->total - $this->commission;
}
```

**Controller**

```php
$sum = Sale::all()->sum->commissionedTotal()
```

This third approach is more elegant and It's the Laravel preferred way.

Comment: Using the approach  2) in an analogous situation , I am getting the following error 

 `ErrorException : stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given.`

 It seems the function inside  sum is not accepting an object as an argument

Answer (score 0):

As per you state in question there only two fileds  a sample query may be:

```
SELECT SUM(s.total-s.commission) as myResult from sales as s WITH (NOLOCK);
```